# How to write test for Ruby on Rails API that is built on an existing database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rest, api, rspec

I am trying to build a read-only Rails API that uses another Rails application's DB as its database.

So far I configured the read-only API's `database.yml` to point to the **existing** databases, generated models via `rails g model` but **did not** run the migration since I already have the corresponding tables in the existing databases.

I wanted to follow TDD approach and started to write tests but my problem is I cannot create instances of models since I did not create the table for that model.

**Example Case**

I generated a model named `project` which exists as a table in the **existing DB** that I am going to use to read data, but since I did not run the migration for that model it does not exist in the current API's DB.

So, I just dumped the `schema.rb` from the existing DB, copied it as my read-only API's `db/schema.rb` and run `rake db:schema:load` when `RAILS_ENV=test`.

I wonder if there's a better way to do this? Is my way of writing a read-only API like this is correct? I am open to any suggestions for this topic.

Cheers.